# yii2 - dynamic activeform and client validation

Tags: yii, yii2

I am rendering an ActiveForm dynamically via ajax, however because the form isn't there on page load, the necessary JS files `yiiActiveForm.js`, `yii.validation.js`) and the associated validation triggers aren't there when the form is echoed out.

Here is some sample code:

JS:

```
$('.btn-edit').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var url = base_url + '/account/editreview/' + id;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            $('.popup').html(result.html);
        }
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
public function actionEditReview($id)
{
    $return_array = [
        'html' => null,
    ];

    $review = $this->findReview($id);

    $return_array['html'] = $this->renderPartial('review-popup', [
        'review' => $review,
    ]);

    echo json_encode($return_array);
}
```

View (review-popup.php):

```
<?php
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'review-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
    'enableClientValidation' => true,
]); ?>

<?php echo $form->field($review, 'title')->textInput(); ?>

<button type="submit" class="btn-edit" data-id="<?php echo $review->id; ?>">Submit</button>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

I have read the notes on this page https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/forms-activeform-js/ but this talks about adding validation to single attributes, and not to an entire form.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: use `renderAjax()` instead of `renderPartial()` when echoing out the view.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#renderAjax()-detail